# Tweaking formatting rules in Vim

Tags: vim, formatting

I am not a Vim noob, but I'm not a pro either. If I have a segment of, in this case javascript, code like so

```
function foo(a,b,c,d) {
if (one||two) {
if (rhyme||reason) {
return true;
}
return false;
}
}
```

and I format it (`gg=G`), I get the following code:

```
function foo(a,b,c,d) {
   if (one||two) {
      if (rhyme||reason) {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

This is more aesthetically pleasing. However, what if instead I had wanted the below (or if I wanted to convert the above result into the below result):

```
function foo( a, b, c, d ) 
{
   if ( one || two ) 
   {
      if ( rhyme || reason ) 
      {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to instruct Vim how to parse code? I can use a hack with regular expressions to find parantheses and pad spaces, but it falls apart when one also considers all the operators (`!,%,*,-,+,=,/`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this vim plugin: https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat

One button press, and you're done.
It uses `gq` and sets external formatprograms in order to uses it properly.

So basically, if you install this plugin along with einars js-beautify, it is able to format javascript out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

Several different comments:

- The `=` operator only handles indentation; unless you override its behavior with `:set equalprg=foo`. It won't change the content of each line.  See `:help =`.
- The `gq` operator will reformat text across lines.  By default, it uses its internal formatter which it accepts options set via `:set formatoptions` (see `:help fo` and `:help fo-table`).  If you know of an external tool that will reformat code the way you want, you can set `formatexpr` (per-buffer) or `formatprg` (globally) to invoke that program when you do `gq`.  See `:help gq`.  Using this instead of `gg=G` just becomes `gggqG`.
- There is a Javascript beautifier plugin on the vim site [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2727).  I haven't used it.  It's just vimscript, so if you want to hack it up to format things exactly the way you want, it's all there for you to use.

Comment: `gq` is more for text. I have it set to `par` and i use it to format comments

Comment: Perhaps I should look for external beautifiers

Comment: I can personally attest to jsbeautify working splendidly well. I have not tried to customize its formatting, but it does more than simply correcting indentation.