# Regex Negations in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, code-formatting

## Question:

How do I convert `var x+=1+2+3+(5+6+7)` to `var x += 1 + 2 + 3 + ( 5 + 6 + 7 )`

## Details:

Using regular expressions, something like `:%s/+/\ x\ /g` won't work because it will convert `+=` to `+ =` (amongst other problems). So instead one would use negations (negatives, nots, whatever they're called) like so `:%s/\s\@!+/\ +/g`, which is about as complicated a way as one can say "plus sign without an empty space before it". But now this converts something like `x++` into `x + +`. What I need is something more complex. I need more than one constraint in the negation, and an additional constraint afterwards. Something like so, but this doesn't work `:%s/[\s+]\@!+\x\@!/\ +/g`

Could someone please provide the one, or possibly two regex statements which will pad out an example operator, such that I can model the rest of my rules on it/them.

## Motivation:

I find beautifiers for languages like javascript or PHP don't give me full control (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853710/tweaking-formatting-rules-in-vim)). Therefore, I am attempting to use regex to carry out the following conversions:

- `foo(1,2,3,4)` → `foo( 1, 2, 3, 4 )`
- `var x=1*2*3` → `var x = 1 * 2 * 3`
- `var x=1%2%3` → `var x = 1 % 2 % 3`
- `var x=a&&b&&c` → `var x = a && b && c`
- `var x=a&b&c` → `var x = a & b & c`

Any feedback would also be appreciated

Comment: regexes only work when you've got regular inputs. your language is somewhat irregular, so it's going to be painful/impossible to get one regex that can handle all variations.

Comment: @MarcB I was thinking a different rule for every operator (ie. one for `+`, one for `+=` one for `-`...) and I realize it would not work for insanely complex expressions like `var x+=x+++++y`)

Comment: @loldop now I feel pretty stupid for not thinking about that. `\w` might actually solve all of my problems

Comment: `\w` will find alphabetic or numeric symbols

Comment: but your regular expression will be more heavy :\ you should make 2 regexps, one for functions, another for expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the great feedback, I now have a regular expression like so to work from. I am running these two regular expressions:

```
:%s/\(\w\)\([+\-*\/%|&~)=]\)/\1\ \2/g
:%s/\([+\-*\/%|&~,(=]\)\(\w\)/\1\ \2/g
```

And it is working fairly well. Here are some results.

```
(1+2+3+4,1+2+3+4,1+2+3+4) --> ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 )
(1-2-3-4,1-2-3-4,1-2-3-4) --> ( 1 - 2 - 3 - 4, 1 - 2 - 3 - 4, 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 )
(1*2*3*4,1*2*3*4,1*2*3*4) --> ( 1 * 2 * 3 * 4, 1 * 2 * 3 * 4, 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 )
(1/2/3/4,1/2/3/4,1/2/3/4) --> ( 1 / 2 / 3 / 4, 1 / 2 / 3 / 4, 1 / 2 / 3 / 4 )
(1%2%3%4,1%2%3%4,1%2%3%4) --> ( 1 % 2 % 3 % 4, 1 % 2 % 3 % 4, 1 % 2 % 3 % 4 )
(1|2|3|4,1|2|3|4,1|2|3|4) --> ( 1 | 2 | 3 | 4, 1 | 2 | 3 | 4, 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 )
(1&2&3&4,1&2&3&4,1&2&3&4) --> ( 1 & 2 & 3 & 4, 1 & 2 & 3 & 4, 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 )
(1~2~3~4,1~2~3~4,1~2~3~4) --> ( 1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4, 1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4, 1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4 )
(1&&2&&3&&4,1&&2&&3&&4,1&&2&&3&&4) --> ( 1 && 2 && 3 && 4, 1 && 2 && 3 && 4, 1 && 2 && 3 && 4 )
(1||2||3||4,1||2||3||4,1||2||3||4) --> ( 1 || 2 || 3 || 4, 1 || 2 || 3 || 4, 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 )
var x=1+(2+(3+4*(965%(123/(456-789))))); --> var x = 1 +( 2 +( 3 + 4 *( 965 %( 123 /( 456 - 789 )))));
```

It seems to work fine for everything except nested brackets. If I fix the nested brackets problem, I will update it here.

Comment: You can try to overcome the issue with parentheses' spacing by using the substitution command `:%s/\(\w\|)\)\zs\ze[+\-*\/%|&~)=]\|[+\-*\/%|&~,(=]\zs\ze\(\w\|(\)/ /g`.